# Where is Motif used today?

Tags: x11, gui, motif

At my University there is a course called “Programming with Motif”.

It being quite an old framework, I am wondering where Motif / programs made with Motif are used today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It tends to be used in old software (*i.e.* software which has been around for a long time, not necessarily obsolete software); for example:

- [Alliance](https://www-soc.lip6.fr/equipe-cian/logiciels/alliance/)
- the [Common Desktop Environment](http://cdesktopenv.sourceforge.net/)
- [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) (OK, that one's probably obsolete)
- [Geomview](http://www.geomview.org)
- [Grace](https://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/)
- of course, the [Motif Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_Window_Manager)
- [NEdit](https://nedit.sourceforge.io/)
- [OpenDX](http://www.opendx.org)
- [Xpdf](http://www.xpdfreader.com/) before version 4

For some reason lots of "scientific" software still uses Motif: [ARB](http://www.arb-home.de), [ESO-MIDAS](http://www.eso.org/projects/esomidas/)... And some software still supports Motif, although by default it doesn't use it any more: examples include [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Motif-Resources.html) and [Vim](http://www.vim.org/).

[The MotifZone wiki](https://motif.ics.com/wiki/) has [a list of Motif applications](https://motif.ics.com/wiki/software-map), but many of the links there are broken.

Comment: FWIW, Vim also has a Motif interface. I suppose a course in using Motif could be useful in the same was as a C++-based course in object oriented programming could be useful if one wanted to learn OO, even if one isn't interested in C++.

Answer (score 6):

I like it because it's (mostly) simple.  If you're going to learn to program for X you need to use some widget set, Motif is probably less of a distraction from studying the underlying layers than say GTK or QT.  And once you've learned the underlying stuff it's easier to see what's sitting on top of it as just that.  Kind of like the more programming languages you know, the easier it is to learn another.  So spending a semester learning it is akin to spending a semester with assembly language.

And I'm still writing with it, or trying to, because it's just a widget set, I'm satisfied with the way the widgets look and work.

Answer (score 3):

Our complete (really big) system (www.invep.de) is completely written in Motif. It's under continuous development until today. I like Motif because it's very fast, absolutely stable and it's even possible to create a modern look and feel.